# Survival function equal to the product integral in discrete random variable

Tags: self-study, survival

How can I prove the survival function equal to the product integral in the  random variable?
\begin{align}
S(t) &= \prod_{0}^{t}(1-d\Lambda(u))  \\
\end{align}

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: If you define $\Lambda$ in terms of $S$ (as is typical), then this result follows Theorem 3 in Gill and Johansen 1990 "A survey of product integration ..."

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the equality above, then that is the definition of the product integral. If you mean how to get to the known relation of survival and hazard, then take a look at the [basic formulas of product integrals on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral), for example.